# Error installing Msysgit - Cygwin seems to be in your system path

Tags: cygwin, msysgit

When I install the Msysgit netinstall 1.9.0 in Windows I get the error:

```
Error: Cygwin seems to be in your system path
```

I Previously installed Cygwin, but I deleted the folder **C:\cygwin**.

In Path inside Environment Variables, there doesn't seem to be any Cygwin path (e.g x:\Cygwin\bin).

No Cygwin services are running.

I use Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. 
It was simple, there are a official instructions to unistall Cygwin:

http://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-all

I forgot delete the registry tree **Software\Cygwin** under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** and/or **HKEY_CURRENT_USER**.